# How to include seasonality in GLM(Genralized Linear Modeling) for time series forecasting?

Tags: time-series, generalized-linear-model, forecasting

The below count is a monthly count of policies sold, it is seasonal in nature

```
glmUsPolicyCount <- glm.nb(usPolicyCount ~ ., data = tempUsPolicyCount)
```

I am able to write the below code to forecast.
How can I specify seasonality in the above model and use it for forecasting? Should I create dummy variables to indicate seasonality and use them as regressors??

```
glmPredUsPolicyCount <- data.table(yrAndMo = countryLvlRegDatTest$yrAndMo, predUsPolicyCount = predict(glmUsPolicyCount, tempUsSumOfFaceCountryTestRegressor, type = 'response'))
```

I am not authorized to share data
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: You can have seasonal dummies or you can code sin and cos components. If you include all the components the fit will be the same (though if you're seeking a parsimonious description and account for the variable selection issues in proper fashion you can often get an excellent good description with fewer).